# Java regex accepting only email with .ca domain

Tags: java, regex

i'm really really bad with regexes. can anyone help me build a java regex that accept only email finishing with .ca.

i've tried something like

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*
      @[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.ca$;
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm really, really good at closing questions that show no attempt.

Comment: Think about what is common to all valid e-mail addresses and create (or copy) a regex that matches it. Then adapt it for Canadian domains

Comment: Hint: You don't use regex for that.

Comment: Giant clue-by-four: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the spirit of teaching you how to fish...  these are all directly relevant to problems with your attempt and might help you improve.

- one trend i see in your regex code is that you are escaping `.` to make it literal by using `\\.`.  By double-escaping it you are saying that you want a literal slash followed by a single character wildcard.  So that should be `\.`  I see you doing this for other special characters too.
- it may be easier for you to write these special characters in class format like this `[.]`.  that means literal dot as well and doesn't use any escaping.
- you don't need to escape special characters in a character class.  I think you did this for `\\+`
- you can write `[A-Za-z]` simpler as `[A-z]`
- `[0-9]` could be written as `[\d]`
- `[_A-z0-9]` coudl be written as `[\w]`
- You're missing a closing `)`

To get you going immediately this should work:

```
([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)(ca)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)(ca)
```